# "This statement is false" - Propositional Logic

Tags: logic, terminology, propositional-calculus

In a [text](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0395286972) I am reading, the section on Propositional Logic says that a *proposition* is a statement that is either *true* or *false*, but not both true and false. Also, from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xlUFkMKSB3Y) lecture online, the instructor says that we must be able to associate a truth value to a proposition.

The text I mentioned contains as an example of an assertion that is *not* a proposition the following:

(1) "this statement is false."

In the margin, the text says that the form of this statement makes it impossible to designate a truth value to it and the instructor in the lecture says simply that, "if [the statement] is true, then it is false, and if it is false, then it is true."

However, why exactly is it impossible to for (1) to have a truth value? What does it mean to say that if (1) is true, it is false, and conversely?

**Response to Asaf Karagila**
As has been pointed out, I have already asked this question very recently [yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1697691/this-statement-is-false) but it has not received proper attention. This question is one that I feel can be put to rest if only someone would provide an explanation that is direct and suitable for my level, which is that of a novice.

Comment: Honestly, this is a bad example that's not really worth considering. It won't hinder your understanding of the subject to ignore this.

Comment: @Kaynex It bothers me tremendously to skip it though.

Comment: I would say that we CAN assign a truth value to it, but neither would be correct. Others might say that because we cannot have a correct truth value, we can't assign one. Either way, as long as you understand what a proposition is, you're fine.

Comment: @Kaynex It's excruciating to ignore this but I think you're right. This is not an example that's helpful for a beginner.

Comment: @Kaynex, philosophically, I'd say its pretty interesting. It shows that the English language is altogether too expressive for the purposes of mathematics, and thereby provides one justification of the use of formal languages in mathematics.

Comment: What even is an example of an assertion that is *both* true and false?

Comment: You should at least mention that you've already asked about this. Yesterday. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1697691/this-statement-is-false

Comment: @AsafKaragila Fixed.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, should we close one of them?

Comment: @goblin Yes, the other one.

Comment: Ha! Not the proper attention? You received *three* answers that had to guess your knowledge and mathematical aptitude. You want better suited answers? Write better questions.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You're right, which is why I tried to ask a better one in this post. I'm genuinely just wanting to put this question behind me, but via an explanation that is appropriate for someone at my level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me toss my 2 cents for what your instructor said.

Suppose (1) "this statement is false." holds. Then the assertion inside "" is false. Thus *this statement is false* does not hold, or (if we abide by the binary logic) *this statement is true*.

Now suppose (1) "this statement is false." does not hold. Then that statement must be true (as long as we abide by the binary logic.) So the assertion *this statement is false* is true.

The bottom line is,
the statement inside "" does not conform to the binary logic.

Comment: Right, if we suppose that (1) is true, then what it claims is the case. And what it claims is that it is false. The same sort of thing occurs when we suppose that (1) is false. Now what's happening here? What does it mean for something to be false if and only if its is true?

Comment: It means that it does not conform to the binary logic.

Comment: I agree that it doesn't "conform to the binary logic," by which I interpret as meaning that it can't be said to be definitely true or definitely false. But a fear that I have is being asked about this and having to say that without really understanding why. I mean, does the statement have an "unstable" truth value?

Comment: I don't know if the statement conforms to an $n$-ary logic for some suitable $n \geq 3$ (I am sceptical if there exists such an $n$, though.)  I would reply to your instructor that we cannot create a truth table since we cannot decide the truth value for that statement.