# If statement p is false. And i say p is false, then p is true?

Tags: logic

Why does false, false result in true ? As i stated. I do not love mathematics is not true is <=> i love mathematics. How could we explain that with logic ? Double negation ? could we say that saying false is the same thing as taking the negation ? and double-negation results in elimnation ? Please help and provide a good answer.

Comment: instead of downvoting i would appreciate an answer. Really do not know what people hope to achieve with simply downvoting

Comment: Here are some useful links  
 :   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/931234/is-proof-by-contradiction-same-thing-as-a-rightarrow-b-is-true-when-a-is?rq=1      https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1697691/this-statement-is-false?rq=1      https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1699654/this-statement-is-false-propositional-logic

Comment: i mean if i assume p is false and this clears out to be false then p must be true

Comment: "Why does false, false result in true ?" What does it mean ?

Comment: To say that "I do not love mathematics" is not TRUE is to say that "I do not love mathematics" is FALSE. But if it is false that I do not love mathematics, this means that I love mathematics. Fullstop.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA i mean if i assume p is false and this clears out to be false then p must be true

Comment: Maybe you're looking for this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negation

Answer (score 1):

No you are getting a bit confused: if $p$ is false, the "$p$ is false" is another statement $q$, not $p$ itself. And clearly:

$$q=\neg p$$

:)

Comment: do you know what i mean ? i mean if i assume p is false and this clears out to be false then p must be true

Comment: Yes clearly if $q=\neg p$ than if the stament $q$ is false.$\neg q=\neg \neg p$ , which for double negation is $\neg q=p$

Comment: eureka do you have books or literature to recommend, i do not wanna ask always here, as i get to many downvotes :/

Comment: @ÖmerF.Yi I don't know books, however this is formal logic. You shouldn't leave this site, it's amazing. You should just learn to be more clear and to write a good post.

Comment: could you please so kind and sum it up again clearly and in simple english ?

Comment: @ÖmerF.Yi the comment or the answer?

Comment: the answer. i appreciate long versions with clear english

Comment: does is false means simply taking the negation of a statement ?

Comment: @ÖmerF.Yi yes if it's true that it is false.

Answer (score 0):

If $p$ is false, and you say "$p$ is false", then the statement "$p$ is false" is true, but $p$ is still false.
If you say "$p$ is false", and it turns out that this is wrong, then the statement "$p$ is false" is false, and $p$ is true$^1$.
"$p$" and "$p$ is false" are two diffeerent statements.

$^1$ (This is assuming that all statements are either true or false, as classical logic does; there are logics which assume more than two truth values or truth-value gaps.)

Comment: hen the statement " is false" is false, and  is true. im asking for that why is this ?

Comment: That's just the meaning of the word "false"...

Comment: false means taking the negation ? since p is wrong the nefation would be true, right ?

Comment: @Ömer F. Yi Yes.

Comment: brilliant, that was my question.